# If else statement for condition contains specific string only

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I want to load my style-sheet's and script's inside wordpress header to show documentation in my front-page/homepage for  specific condition supply by wordpress option setting `get_option('my_main_scripts')`.

Pool of values for this option setting are `javascript library, javascript yui, javascript jquery, javascript dojo` and so on. All option value consist with common word `javascript`.
and want to load css if any one value is selected from the pool which contains word `javascript`.

So writing condition with each option using OR (||) , I think its better to grab the common word from the value and write down the condition .here is `javascript` how can I get this?

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_front_page()  ) { ?>

<?php if (get_option('my_main_scripts') == "javascript library"): ?>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/css/javadoc.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/javadoc.dojo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/javadoc.yui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo("template_url"); ?>/js/javadoc.jquery.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<?php get_template_part('documation'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

```
if(strpos(get_option('my_main_scripts'),'javascript') !== false )
```

Also have a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
if(preg_match('/javascript/',get_option('my_main_scripts')))
```

Comment: What if my option values contains special character like javascript+dojo, javascript-jquery. then also urs suggestion works or what?

Comment: Thanks Rikesh! I have tested and its work's for me. But I m checking for more lengthy strings which doesn't contains spaces and mixed up with special character.